# TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: “CL.exe”. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: cl.exe

- I'm using VS community 2019, cmake-3.14.0-win32-x86 and Windows 8.1
- I'm trying to install sdl1:x64-windows package via C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe:

C:\Users\triki\vcpkg> .\vcpkg install sdl1:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    sdl1[core]:x64-windows
Starting package 1/1: sdl1:x64-windows
Building package sdl1[core]:x64-windows...
-- Using cached C:/Users/triki/vcpkg/downloads/SDL-Mirror-SDL-release-1.2.15.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/Users/triki/vcpkg/buildtrees/sdl1/src/ase-1.2.15-086d8ac6c2
-- Building VisualC/SDL1_2017.sln for Release
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:72 (message):
    Command failed: msbuild C:/Users/triki/vcpkg/buildtrees/sdl1/x64-windows-rel/ase-1.2.15-086d8ac6c2/VisualC/SDL1_2017.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild/p:UseEnv=True /p:Platform=x64 /p:PlatformToolset=v142 /p:VCPkgLocalAppDataDisabled=true/p:UseIntelMKL=No /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion= /m
    Working Directory: C:/Users/triki/vcpkg/buildtrees/sdl1/x64-windows-rel/ase-1.2.15-086d8ac6c2
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\triki\vcpkg\buildtrees\sdl1\build-x64-windows-rel-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_msbuild.cmake:160 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)

ports/sdl1/portfile.cmake:29 (vcpkg_install_msbuild)
  scripts/ports.cmake:90 (include)

Error: Building package sdl1:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with .\vcpkg update, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: sdl1:x64-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2020.02.04-nohash

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.

- I have checked the logs in C:\Users\triki\vcpkg\buildtrees\sdl1\build-x64-windows-rel-out.log and found the following error:

2>TRACKER: TRK0005 error: failure to locate : "CL.exe". The specified file cannot be found. [C:\Users\triki\vcpkg\buildtrees\sdl1\x64-windows-rel\ase-1.2.15-086d8ac6c2\VisualC\SDL\SDL.vcxproj]

- So the problem is that cmake doesn't find the compiler
- The Compiler "CL.exe" is avaible in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
- I added a Path named `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to the Compiler Directory but still not working
- Notice that I become the same problem everytime I want to install a new package

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error what I've done is to add the folder where you have "CL.exe" into Executable Directories. Specifically, you go to your Project properties/VC++ Directories/Executable Directories and there you add the path. Then you apply the changes, clean and rebuild and it should work.
Be careful to do it in the right configuration (Debug/Release) and platform you're using to compile.

For info, I had "CL.exe" in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX64\x64* and *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64* folders, and the other directories combinations (HostX64\x86, HostX86\x64 and HostX86\x86).